# Java Kerberos authentication seems to work, still gets rejected

Tags: java, kerberos, spnego, gssapi

I've got a Java client app and a Java server app, and I'm trying to authenticate to the server via Kerberos. The client basically uses http-components and SPNEGO to make a HTTP GET call, but I always get `401 Unauthorized` as a result.

I can not spot the error in the Kerberos login sequence below, maybe you guys can:

```
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache false useKeyTab false doNotPrompt f
alse ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is fa
lse principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is f
alse clearPass is false
Kerberos-Benutzername [GP_Myuser]: GP_Myuser@EESERV.LOCAL
Kerberos-Passwort f³r GP_Myuser@EESERV.LOCAL:
                [Krb5LoginModule] user entered username: GP_Myuser@EESERV.
LOCAL

default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23.
Acquire TGT using AS Exchange
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23.
>>> KrbAsReq calling createMessage
>>> KrbAsReq in createMessage
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=atlnztdc01.eeserv.local UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=144
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=atlnztdc01.eeserv.local UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt=1, #bytes=144
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=181
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=181
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove atlnztdc01.eeserv.local:88
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11
>>>KRBError:
         sTime is Tue Jul 05 16:28:31 CEST 2011 1309876111000
         suSec is 250145
         error code is 25
         error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
         realm is EESERV.LOCAL
         sname is krbtgt/EESERV.LOCAL
         eData provided.
         msgType is 30
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 11
         PA-ETYPE-INFO etype = 23
         PA-ETYPE-INFO salt =
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 19
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 salt = null
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 2
         PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 16
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 15
AcquireTGT: PREAUTH FAILED/REQUIRED, re-send AS-REQ
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23.
>>>KrbAsReq salt is EESERV.LOCALGP_Myuser
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23.
Pre-Authenticaton: find key for etype = 23
AS-REQ: Add PA_ENC_TIMESTAMP now
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbAsReq calling createMessage
>>> KrbAsReq in createMessage
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=atlnztdc01.eeserv.local UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of
 retries =3, #bytes=222
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=atlnztdc01.eeserv.local UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt=1, #bytes=222
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1450
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1450
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove atlnztdc01.eeserv.local:88
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply GP_Myuser
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23.
principal is GP_Myuser@EESERV.LOCAL
EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=0000: 3D F9 1C A6 3B 94 7B 27   B3
 6C D7 E5 70 77 84 22  =...;..'.l..pw."

Commit Succeeded

Found ticket for GP_Myuser@EESERV.LOCAL to go to krbtgt/EESERV.LOCAL@EESER
V.LOCAL expiring on Wed Jul 06 02:28:32 CEST 2011
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: same realm
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 23.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=atlnztdc01.eeserv.local UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of
 retries =3, #bytes=1452
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=atlnztdc01.eeserv.local UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt
=1, #bytes=1452
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1436
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1436
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove atlnztdc01.eeserv.local:88
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbApReq: APOptions are 00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
Krb5Context setting mySeqNumber to: 512880730
Created InitSecContextToken:
0000: 01 00 6E 82 05 51 30 82   05 4D A0 03 02 01 05 A1  ..n..Q0..M......
0010: 03 02 01 0E A2 07 03 05   00 20 00 00 00 A3 82 04  ......... ......
0020: 6E 61 82 04 6A 30 82 04   66 A0 03 02 01 05 A1 0E  na..j0..f.......
0030: 1B 0C 45 45 53 45 52 56   2E 4C 4F 43 41 4C A2 24  ..EESERV.LOCAL.$
0040: 30 22 A0 03 02 01 00 A1   1B 30 19 1B 04 48 54 54  0".......0...HTT
0050: 50 1B 11 61 6C 66 2D 74   65 73 74 2E 65 6C 69 6E  P..alf-test.server
0060: 2E 63 6F 6D A3 82 04 27   30 82 04 23 A0 03 02 01  .com...'0..#....
0070: 17 A1 03 02 01 03 A2 82   04 15 04 82 04 11 C2 1E  ................
0080: 14 D0 18 19 AF 82 D3 92   7F 62 96 A9 92 F7 94 5B  .........b.....[
0090: FF CA FE 66 2F C8 A9 C6   36 A2 2E FF EB FB CA 3D  ...f/...6......=
00A0: 5D 5B 59 B5 0F E3 B7 B6   29 C2 62 A3 45 44 42 00  ][Y.....).b.EDB.
00B0: DA 14 3D 83 1E 50 3D AA   A9 9F 0C A6 49 4E F3 51  ..=..P=.....IN.Q
00C0: 67 68 14 A4 D3 49 E6 6F   1C 2C 7D 04 7B F2 6E BD  gh...I.o.,....n.
00D0: 23 07 DD CD 09 DC 89 62   73 0E 06 EE 68 28 39 A4  #......bs...h(9.
00E0: 22 3C 92 C0 22 C0 6B 0B   42 4B 95 B5 E5 AC 77 30  "<..".k.BK....w0
00F0: D8 75 A1 8D E8 FC A5 5A   D6 1D A8 5B D4 15 82 C5  .u.....Z...[....
0100: AE 1E 36 48 72 01 9B 3C   FA A9 60 20 1D 9A 84 20  ..6Hr..<..` ...
0110: 41 3F FA 71 A8 07 9C 50   73 FA 03 2B 8D 94 98 C8  A?.q...Ps..+....
0120: 57 A2 87 09 BF 87 26 62   2B 49 40 6A 67 C4 F1 00  W.....&b+I@jg...
0130: 66 55 D7 75 6D A6 2F 28   3C 68 86 1F 29 E1 7E 10  fU.um./(<h..)...
0140: CD 2B F0 78 A7 23 D9 18   8D 5D 98 F9 7D 00 11 78  .+.x.#...].....x
0150: 7B 5E D3 5E EA EE 74 82   B7 93 A4 DA 0E 3C 61 E6  .^.^..t......<a.
0160: B3 D5 5A F3 67 8C 03 4C   0E E6 42 96 8F E0 99 98  ..Z.g..L..B.....
0170: C2 A0 C6 D3 8F B4 A4 CA   99 C1 8A F0 6E 00 E0 BE  ............n...
0180: 95 7F 1F F5 E7 15 3D 0F   CD 22 51 D9 41 D0 5F 01  ......=.."Q.A._.
0190: 48 EB 47 64 B8 74 BC BE   76 0F AE 4B F4 E6 3A 1E  H.Gd.t..v..K..:.
01A0: 2A 62 85 FA 7E 07 E7 8D   60 EC B9 23 10 E3 1B 1E  *b......`..#....
01B0: C5 90 D2 25 BB C5 2C 05   A3 E2 39 D1 FF 70 CF E7  ...%..,...9..p..
01C0: D5 C6 13 E6 BC 60 55 89   C1 B9 FB 0F E4 5D E7 A5  .....`U......]..
01D0: 95 BA F9 70 EC 06 CB 62   E8 AD F3 29 BA 34 FF C2  ...p...b...).4..
01E0: 95 76 21 9B 0D 0B DE 66   05 0E EE 33 31 E7 BE 52  .v!....f...31..R
01F0: 64 DB 91 8B 55 96 5F E7   2D 2A EA E2 D3 BC 5F CD  d...U._.-*...._.
0200: 46 E5 45 A1 07 68 28 BF   1D 32 7D 04 C0 60 97 78  F.E..h(..2...`.x
0210: 4F 8E 4C 92 2B F1 B2 C3   9B 04 D9 43 02 7F A5 27  O.L.+......C...'
0220: A4 8E 48 EE 5E A9 3B 7E   7F C0 54 0D A5 75 D2 B3  ..H.^.;...T..u..
0230: FC 72 3A 80 F4 9A F1 34   7C 51 54 13 F7 9E FE 79  .r:....4.QT....y
0240: 8F 15 5A A7 9E 47 9B 36   10 33 F3 08 EA F2 33 BB  ..Z..G.6.3....3.
0250: 9F 45 61 ED 91 1F CF 30   05 76 C0 56 FB 38 51 25  .Ea....0.v.V.8Q%
0260: 27 1F 39 A5 C9 F9 0C D2   00 F2 6B E2 28 09 B2 30  '.9.......k.(..0
0270: A2 63 68 FE 46 A5 33 E0   60 BB B2 B5 DA 5A 78 2A  .ch.F.3.`....Zx*
0280: 37 FE 16 0D 8E E6 97 52   47 28 B2 D0 92 DB F3 CD  7......RG(......
0290: 9A 5F 98 16 4E C9 96 2C   00 7C FE 96 B0 DE CD 6D  ._..N..,.......m
02A0: 5A BC 13 1B E2 E7 F6 74   DE DC 2B B7 16 AB C0 0F  Z......t..+.....
02B0: BA 4C 08 C3 4F 25 3C 1A   9A E5 36 32 8E D9 C7 10  .L..O%<...62....
02C0: 62 F2 13 BB 62 B4 C5 F2   9D 69 DB 6C 0C 37 E1 AF  b...b....i.l.7..
02D0: F5 C6 D9 CD B5 F6 60 A2   93 DD 98 8C B2 59 C7 7A  ......`......Y.z
02E0: 50 4D 27 7B CC DA C9 28   9D 05 9C E8 FC 57 F8 4A  PM'....(.....W.J
02F0: 12 67 ED 7E 23 AB B5 FB   8A B7 CE 4D DA 1B 7F 1A  .g..#......M....
0300: B3 6F DF 42 9F C4 90 C9   35 D9 77 33 CD 6C C5 B5  .o.B....5.w3.l..
0310: C2 A8 15 8C AE BD AE 5F   0A 0A AB 7C 8C F8 E2 9F  ......._........
0320: 27 3C 27 85 B3 97 D9 9D   DA 6E 56 25 3B BA D5 FB  '<'......nV%;...
0330: AB 24 8B BE B7 26 12 7F   B6 25 E5 26 DE 8D 54 AA  .$...&...%.&..T.
0340: 0B 68 DB 4B 81 AD 9C FD   88 0F 7D 6A 97 79 E5 0F  .h.K.......j.y..
0350: 5B 82 43 6F 05 AE C0 EB   77 A6 E3 39 BE 85 6E F0  [.Co....w..9..n.
0360: B5 F5 0B 13 E7 CC 7B 1E   81 4F 37 77 BB 02 26 C2  .........O7w..&.
0370: D7 2C 80 CD 62 91 A7 0C   F8 D1 76 5C 21 39 A0 93  .,..b.....v\!9..
0380: 83 04 0A F7 1F C3 4B 0B   34 85 2D 90 75 4E FE 31  ......K.4.-.uN.1
0390: 61 BF D8 F3 36 B5 40 BA   06 F8 47 33 D4 DD EE 2A  a...6.@...G3...*
03A0: 9C FB 5E 51 7A 25 F7 C1   3F 4D 58 73 F2 4A 50 EA  ..^Qz%..?MXs.JP.
03B0: 68 09 27 85 F3 2E BB EA   8E B4 D3 7C DC 3B 52 71  h.'..........;Rq
03C0: 87 34 1B 6F 80 D1 D2 F1   7D C3 9E C4 C3 79 8A A7  .4.o.........y..
03D0: DA 0B A2 69 7C DE D5 67   C7 20 AD 97 A2 98 6A E3  ...i...g. ....j.
03E0: A3 59 BD D2 B6 19 18 1D   AB A7 58 3A 56 16 ED 2A  .Y........X:V..*
03F0: 75 73 4E DB 02 B5 77 4B   F5 9D 1D A4 36 ED 39 26  usN...wK....6.9&
0400: B8 A4 CD 7C 79 5E 11 3C   36 9D DA DA E7 F5 D2 9F  ....y^.<6.......
0410: BA 4B 45 E0 67 E5 4F 33   9E 0B 60 E6 76 EB 02 AC  .KE.g.O3..`.v...
0420: CC 24 C4 EB 37 C4 31 B7   EA F3 EA 5B 39 D6 E3 0A  .$..7.1....[9...
0430: DC F8 DE 8B 18 8C E0 25   5C 4B 85 38 B0 99 04 9C  .......%\K.8....
0440: 61 75 17 E3 E6 0C 88 D9   7B C4 9A 2D 25 B3 C1 FE  au.........-%...
0450: 9F FD 12 4F E0 DF CF E6   C1 BA 68 00 32 E8 1F 9A  ...O......h.2...
0460: 2F 0E FB 44 59 53 8B 43   C5 B6 24 D3 76 B4 04 D2  /..DYS.C..$.v...
0470: 39 A9 21 41 EC A3 78 D1   9B 07 64 10 5B 64 EB 18  9.!A..x...d.[d..
0480: 08 5B 2C 45 90 53 C9 90   A0 4C 15 AF 8A D4 80 A4  .[,E.S...L......
0490: 81 C5 30 81 C2 A0 03 02   01 17 A2 81 BA 04 81 B7  ..0.............
04A0: CB D6 6F 4E E7 6C 78 93   EF 6D EA 0C C8 A9 6B 37  ..oN.lx..m....k7
04B0: EB 0E 9C C5 86 9E E6 BA   0D 88 26 BA FE A8 83 86  ..........&.....
04C0: D4 06 52 50 AF 48 BC 8F   66 08 F1 1E A4 97 5E 05  ..RP.H..f.....^.
04D0: 24 B4 DC 44 94 F3 5D 3D   07 17 10 33 15 D8 E0 0C  $..D..]=...3....
04E0: E8 E8 0F 70 E6 23 B3 FF   D5 23 63 02 A4 6B 86 C9  ...p.#...#c..k..
04F0: 88 96 FA 8B 02 3C E6 C6   19 7E 86 58 D5 07 80 8F  .....<.....X....
0500: 21 10 7A F8 2D E2 C0 AE   33 19 A3 87 8F 18 03 A0  !.z.-...3.......
0510: 22 13 37 66 D5 CA 02 02   E9 51 87 D5 E5 7D 3E 84  ".7f.....Q....>.
0520: 6E 62 4A 0B 04 8D CF 79   07 DE 69 3B 49 95 B1 80  nbJ....y..i;I...
0530: F4 9A 86 62 8D BD F4 DA   FB BC 69 97 9A 8D DE 92  ...b......i.....
0540: 0E 8A 65 E7 7C 62 E1 3D   E6 93 AD 6F 0A 53 00 B0  ..e..b.=...o.S..
0550: 2F E7 09 A6 1B 01 72                               /.....r

05.07.2011 16:28:33 org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when proces
sing request: The target server failed to respond
05.07.2011 16:28:33 org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
----------------------------------------
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=/share/page?pt=login">
</head><body><p>Please <a href="/share/page?pt=login">log in</a>.</p>
</body></html>

----------------------------------------
```

Comment: couple of things. What is the target SPN you have provided as an argument and what Realm have you set in the web.xml of the required servlet? You can set JAAS Realm for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your Kerberos configuration might be completely fine. The 401 messsage means that the authentication itself probably went fine. However, i suspect the webapp only allows users if they are assigned a Role. The SPNego mechanism does not assign such role out-of-the-box. You still need to configure a Realm that performs the mapping.

See also my question on the Tomcat users mailing list.
https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201210.mbox/%3C5075ECC6.8060501@christopherschultz.net%3E

Answer (score 0):

What library do you use on the server side? Did you enable debug flags to see what happens when the server processes the service ticket?

Comment: The server is a Tomcat with Alfresco running on it. The JVM Kerberos support is used. I've not yet looked at the server in detail, because I thought the login process didn't work. Does the snipped I posted look like a successful auth. to you?

Comment: It seems to be fine but you need to share server output. Do you use a tomcat authenticator or is this some built-in feature in Alfresco. Don't know if Alf... has already built-in Krb5 support. Beware that SPNEGO, this is what you do, is supported in Java 6 only.