# SSO Configuration with Weblogic 11g OEL

Tags: linux, oracle, weblogic, single-sign-on, kerberos

I'm receiving following error in Weblogic while accessing application through AD user for SSO.

```
> <> <> <1471875042422> <BEA-000000> <com.bea.common.security.internal.legacy.service.ChallengeIdentityAssertionProviderImpl$ChallengeIdentityAsserterV2Adapter.assertChallengeIdentity(Authorization.Negotiate)>
####<22-Aug-2016 15:10:42 o'clock BST> <Debug> <SecurityAtn> <ndl-wln-100.centricait.com> <ND_Manage1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1471875042422> <BEA-000000> <GSSExceptionInfo:>
####<22-Aug-2016 15:10:42 o'clock BST> <Debug> <SecurityAtn> <ndl-wln-100.centricait.com> <ND_Manage1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1471875042423> <BEA-000000> <   major: (13) : No valid credentials provided>
####<22-Aug-2016 15:10:42 o'clock BST> <Debug> <SecurityAtn> <ndl-wln-100.centricait.com> <ND_Manage1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1471875042423> <BEA-000000> <   minor: (-1) : Failed to find any Kerberos credentails>
####<22-Aug-2016 15:10:42 o'clock BST> <Debug> <SecurityAtn> <ndl-wln-100.centricait.com> <ND_Manage1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1471875042423> <BEA-000000> <acceptGssInitContextToken failed
com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos credentails)
        at com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosTokenHandler.acceptGssInitContextTokenInDoAs(KerberosTokenHandler.java:334)
        at com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosTokenHandler.access$000(KerberosTokenHandler.java:41)
        at com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosTokenHandler$1.run(KerberosTokenHandler.java:226)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
        at com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosTokenHandler.acceptGssInitContextToken(KerberosTokenHandler.java:224)
        at com.bea.security.utils.kerberos.KerberosTokenHandler.acceptGssInitContextToken(KerberosTokenHandler.java:152)
        at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.negotiate.SPNEGONegotiateToken.getUsername(SPNEGONegotiateToken.java:57)
        at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.NegotiateIdentityAsserterProviderImpl.assertChallengeIdentity(NegotiateIdentityAsserterProviderImpl.java:210)
        at com.bea.common.security.internal.legacy.service.ChallengeIdentityAssertionProviderImpl$ChallengeIdentityAsserterV2Adapter.assertChallengeIdentity(ChallengeIdentityAssertionProviderImpl.j
```

I already have verified keytab using `kinit -V -k -t negotestserver.keytab HTTP/WL-HOST@MYDOMAIN.COM` its successfully Authenticated. Wonder whats the solution of this issue any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen for different users? Does this happen on different workstations? Which browser do you use?

Comment: also see my comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041640/weblogic-kerberos-sso/28223529#28223529 to change logging level to see more info in the log.

Comment: misha2400: i m using a test AD user which has assigned roles in Oracle Internet Directory.. I am using IE11... nop i hav't try any other user..and using single client workstation which logged in through VDI

Comment: i have already enable weblgoc atn & atz debugging and have also enable -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true

Comment: did you set up SPN in your AD? Is your IE11 configured to use Integrated Windows Authentication?

Comment: yup i have configured SPN and test it from my OEL Weblogic server using command kinit -V-k -t and it says Authenticated.. also have configure IE 11 for Integrated Windows Authentication..

Comment: i am working since two days on it.. its really frustrating me.. :/

Comment: if you run klist command on workstation, does it show any cached tickets?

Comment: [root@WLHOST-100 Domain]# kinit -V -k -t new.keytab  HTTP/WLHOST-100@MYDOMAIN.COM
Using default cache: persistent:380206332:krb_ccache_IlAjdoE
Using principal: HTTP/WLHOST-100@MYDOMAIN.COM
Using keytab: new.keytab
Authenticated to Kerberos v5
[root@wl-100 DOMAIN]# klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:380206332:krb_ccache_IlAjdoE
Default principal: HTTP/NDL-WLN-100@MYDOMAIN.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
22/08/16 19:51:37  22/08/16 20:01:37  krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.COM@MYDOMAIN.COM

Comment: not on server, on workstation and not "kinit" but "klist".

Comment: yup on client windows machine klist shows tickets as following... D:\Users\NDelius01>klist

Current LogonId is 0:0x2b66043

Cached Tickets: (7)

#0>     Client: NDelius01 @ CENTRICAIT.COM
        Server: krbtgt/CENTRICAIT.COM @ CENTRICAIT.COM
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
        Ticket Flags 0x60a00000 -> forwardable forwarded renewable pre_authen.....

Comment: can you check Event Viewer on windows machine for any Kerberos errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the ticket that's sent from browser to Weblogic is not Kerberos ticket, but NTLM. There can be many reasons why IE would use NTLM over Kerberos, most of the time it's incorrect setup or Windows settings. Can you check the ticket in your log? If it looks something like this:

`YIGCBgYrBgEFBQKgeDB2oDAwLgYKKwYBBAGCNwICCgYJKoZIgvcSAQICBgkqhkiG9xIBAgIGCisGAQQBgjcCAh6iQgRATlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl7II4g4ADgAyAAAACgAKACgAAAAGAbEdAAAAD0xBUFRPUC0yNDVMSUZFQUNDT1VOVExMQw==`

it's NTLM. Kerberos ticket is at least twice as long.

Comment: after patch jdk security files as per this oracle document  For Oracle JDK 7: Download Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 from 

Link : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html . 

Overwrite 2 jar files under “<JAVA_HOME>/jre/lib/security” directory with 2 jar files inside downloaded zip file
the credentials issue seems to resolved but now facing Token not supported by Negotiate Filter, ignoring: NTLM" yup you are right browser is sending NTLM instead of Kerberos.. any fix for this ?

Comment: there were two entries of weblogic host in AD setspn -l machinename after removing them and create new keytab with fully qualified domain name setspn -S HTTP/machinename.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM and ktpass also with FQDN im able to make sso work for weblogic console...but applicaion still not workng

Comment: What are you typing in the browser to get to the application? Same URL as in SPN - machinename.domain.com ?

Comment: Also, can you post the log section with authentication attempt? And your config files will be helpful, too.

Comment: i tried both.. the weblogic console is working with sso on http://servername:7001/console but application is not working.. i haven't any document how to setup application for sso.. i have CLIENT_CERT configured in web.xml

Comment: finaly i make it work after changing nodemanager.properties file with startscriptenable=true :) cheers